# Android Class not covered even after Successfully PIT Mutation Test. need suggesion

Tags: pitest

I faced problem during PIT Mutation Testing. I am able to build maven and able to run Android project as PIT Mutation test. After that, I am getting one index.html, with no coverage file. Can anyone suggest me how to test our Class through PIT Mutation
After set up robolectric,right click on test project and choose, run as Pit mutation test from Eclipse, and the below [Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirAB.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your build file and the log output?

Comment: Thank You Henry, at least you want to help me .I have created one sample project, named PITSample.prj. there is one class MainActivity.class. inside MainActivity, one function Sum() is there. now I want to test through PIT Mutation Test. My doubt is, Do I need to create another test project to test PITSample.prj, and if , then which project do I need to convert as Maven. and what the next procedure. Here, For my test I have converted PITSample.prj as Maven. then, right click on project, select PIT Mutation Test.

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you are doing, but hopefully the following will help. PIT requires the tests and code to be in the same project. It needs real *unit* tests that run on a normal JVM (so pure java code, or use roboelectric). You don't need to use maven - you can also run PIT via gradle,ant or IDE plugins. It sounds as if you are running it from an IDE. If so there is no need to "convert as maven".

Comment: thank you. Can I have one complete procedure doc procedure, for PIT mutation testing(Android application, eclipse). I read pitest.org, i understood how its work, but not clear how to use PIT. what is the procedure. I have googled it lot, but I'm confused to use PIT Mutation. Please help me. I hope I'm not irritating you. I don't know, how to use this tools, and I want this tool, and only you can help me , no one is ready to help me or no one knows exactly about PIT

Comment: For the support tool, we choosen "ROBOELECTRIC" , which is mostly used by most of the developers around the world with PIT.
 We are succesfull with "ROBOELECTRIC" . (ie) we are able to run a standalone android project with "ROBOELECTRIC" tool.
 We have made integration and facing same issue,Not getting expected coverage report.